# How can I add the to the (cart list) the picture displayed on product details

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to store I tried to the productID on the cartMup but it did not work.

This how I'm getting the product ID from the products activity:

```
productID = getIntent().getStringExtra("pid");
private StringproductID = "";
```

Storing the data to the cart List:

```
private void addingToCartList() {

     final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();

     cartMap.put("pid", productID);
     cartMap.put("pname", productName.getText().toString());
     cartMap.put("price", productPrice.getText().toString());
     cartMap.put("discount", "");
     cartMap.put("quantity", numberButton.getNumber());
     cartMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
     cartMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);

     cartListRef.child("User view").child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getEmail()).child("Products").child(productID).updateChildren(cartMap)
     .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

             if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                 cartListRef.child("Admin view").child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getEmail()).child("Products").child(productID).updateChildren(cartMap)
                     .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                     @Override
                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                         if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                             Toast.makeText(ProductDetailsActivity.this, "Product added to
 Cart!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             Intent intent = new Intent(ProductDetailsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);

                             startActivity(intent);
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     });   
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: that's what I'm wandering. Probably I'm missing something. This how I first tried to store the Image     cartMap.put("image", ProductImage);   but unfortunately did not work. Is there another way to store the Image?

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: the code that I used, could not display the product image on the cart list